# How to add entries to mysql db using API..?

Tags: php, mysql, api, mobile, parameters

I am new to PHP and mysql and i am trying to make API's for my iphone app.
So far i have been able to connect and retrive data from my sql database now m trying to make entries to it using API's and parameters.

Can anyone help me out here please.

Thanks alot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by `to make entries` you mean adding data to the database.

You do this in the same way that you `select` data.
Instead of issuing a `select` statement like:

```
SELECT x,y,z FROM table1
```

You do:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (x,y,z) VALUES ('a', 1, 'test')
```

Or:

```
UPDATE table1 SET x = 'b' WHERE x = 'a'
```

How you pass parameters depends on the API you use.
It is best (safest) to use PDO to pass parameters.

**How to get parameters out of a url**
In order to get the parameters out of the url (e.g.: example.com/test.php?username=xyz&password=!@#$%) do:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']);  
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['password']);  
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' 
          AND passhash = sha2(CONCAT(salt,'$password'),512)";
```

Note that it's vital to put single quotes around the injected variable names when using `mysql_real_escape_string()` or the escaping will be useless. Used like this the code is 100% secure from SQL-injection.

If you're using PDO, you can drop the `mysql_real_escape_string()` if not you need it to prevent SQL-injection.

**Links**
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%5Bmysql%5D+pdo
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: Thanks for the reply This i know how to insert data in table using INSERT n UPDATE but i want to do this by hitting a URL example.com/test.php?username=xyz&password=!@#$%

Comment: I know this maybe be the basic thing to ask but i have no idea to make web services. So after hitting that url username row and password should be update in DB.

Comment: Thnx does link worked :) thnx a lot man